# how to highlight active tabs in angular 6

Tags: html, angular

**everthing showing perfect but how to highlight active one am doing without using any third party component  I hope someone can help me with this .

Thanks.**

```
 <ul class="tabs">
<li [ngClass]=" {'active-tab': tab==1 }"><a (click)=" tab = 1 " href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 1</a></li>
<li [ngClass]=" {'active-tab': tab==2 }"><a (click)=" tab = 2 " href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 2</a></li>
<li [ngClass]=" {'active-tab': tab==3 }"><a (click)=" tab = 3 " href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 3</a></li>df
</ul>

<div class="tab-panel" id="tabPanel1" *ngIf="tab==1">
    ABC TAB 1
</div>
<div class="tab-panel" id="tabPanel2" *ngIf="tab==2">
    ABC TAB 2
</div>
<div class="tab-panel" id="tabPanel3" *ngIf="tab==3">
    ABC TAB 3
</div>
```

typescript here

```
home.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  tab: number = 3;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

enter code here
```

Comment: You are conditionally adding `active-tab` class to selected tab item in the list. Use this class in CSS to highlight the list item however you want.

Comment: @Nikhil  by adding active-tab in class not getting highlighted can do show me how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are conditionally adding `active-tab` class to selected tab item in the list. Use this class in CSS to highlight the list item however you want.

You have`<a>` anchor element in list items, but aren't actually using their `href` attribute. Also, anchor elements couldn't be styled easily without overriding their default styles.

You could replace `<a>` anchor elements with `<span>` elements and style them as needed.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li [ngClass]=" {'active-tab': tab==1 }"><span (click)=" tab = 1 ">Tab 1</span></li>
  <li [ngClass]=" {'active-tab': tab==2 }"><span (click)=" tab = 2 ">Tab 2</span></li>
  <li [ngClass]=" {'active-tab': tab==3 }"><span (click)=" tab = 3 ">Tab 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tabs li.active-tab {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Live demo on StackBlitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7eomzn